# how to fix 2 Models showing up at the time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, model

I'm **fetching data from a database** and creating a model for each document of the database. But what happens is; it works well with a single document but when I tried the same with two documents, **both models show up at the same time**.

How can I show one specific model at a time instead of two?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add more details to the question?

Comment: honestly i dont know how i can explain more i'm sorry for that, i thought my question was clear.